# gmail web version add strike through button with greasemonkey in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail, greasemonkey

1. why I can not use DOMNodeInserted to call my function to add buttons to gmail editor?

   window.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", myFunction, false);

I got it working with "click" event, but it seems odd you have to click somewhere in order for the buttons to be added

https://gfycat.com/OfficialYearlyAngelfish
[image]

2. how to I click the "best fit" button programmatically?
3. How to add popup menu to "Insert Image Inline" so that user can choose best fit/ origninal / 60% etc ...

Thanks.

My testing code is here:
https://github.com/oglops/gmail-strike-through-insert-img/blob/dev/gmail-strike-through-insert-img.js